# TestNG xml and Testlink Java API

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, webdriver, testng

im having the following problem, Im running all my test on jenkins and im getting like 10 failures out of 22 tests i have currently. These tests are linked to Testlink to report it's result.

When i run these tests individually they run perfectly either they fail or the pass but when i run 2 difrent classes. Here is were the problems start, some test cases fail because they fail to find the buildplan meaning that the cant find the testcase to were report the result. And im 100% sure that the parameters im passing them is correct, becuase i ran them individually.

Here is an example of the testng.xml and it's format.

```
<parameter name="nombrePlan" value="test1" />
<parameter name="nombreBuild" value="test1build" />
<parameter name="nomTL_1" value="1"/>
<parameter name="nomTL_2" value="2"/>
<parameter name="nomTL_3" value="3"/>

<test name="Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.example.testClass1">
            <methods>
                <include name ="test1" />
                <include name ="test2" />
                <include name ="test3" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<parameter name="nombrePlan" value="test2" />
<parameter name="nombreBuild" value="test2build" />
<parameter name="nomTL_4" value="4" />
<parameter name="nomTL_5" value="5" />
<parameter name="nomTL_6" value="6" />
<parameter name="nomTL_7" value="7"/>
<parameter name="nomTL_8" value="8"/>
<test name="test2">
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.example.testClass2">
            <methods>
                <include name="test4" />
                <include name="test5" />
                <include name="test6" />
                <include name="test7"/>
                <include name="test8"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

This is and example of a test:

```
@Parameters({"nombrePlan", "nombreBuild", "nomTL_1"})
@Test
public void checkMenuElements (String nombrePlan, String nombreBuild, String nomTL_1) throws Exception {
    String resultado = null;
    String nota = null;
    try {
        Class abc = new Class(driver);
        abc.navigateToAbc();
        Test test1 = new Test(driver);
        test1.checkMenuElements();
        resultado =  TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
    }catch(AssertionError a){
        resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
        nota = a.getMessage();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
        nota = e.getMessage();
    }
    finally {
        ResultadoExecucao.reportTestCaseResult(PROJETO, nombrePlan, nomTL_1, nombreBuild, nota, resultado);
    }   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you think reporting is an issue , why dont you execute your tests and have a custom Reporter (or Listener)  for testng implementing Ireporter, report your results to Testlink ? .

Comment: If you think reporting is an issue , why dont you execute your tests and create a custom Reporter (or Listener)  for testng implementing Ireporter and then have the custom reporter report your results to Testlink ? . Pretty basic example can be found at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_custom_reporter.htm

Comment: Thanks, on the reply created a custom Reporter.